# Recovering "$n$" from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is there an example of an infinite-dimensional $C^*$-algebra $A$ which admits the following structure:

The $C^*$ algebra $A$ admits a faithful trace $tr$ such that the multiplication $m: A\otimes A \to A$ would be a bounded operator between pre-Hilbert spaces (with respect to the inner product $tr(ab^*)$ on $A$ and its natural extension to the algebraic tensor product $A\otimes A$) such that $mm^*=\lambda\mathrm{Id}$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, where $m^*$ is the adjoint of $m$ after completion of the above pre Hilbert space? Is there an example of this situation for which $\lambda$ is not an integer number?

**Motivation from finite-dimensional 
 case:** For $A=M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the standard trace we have $\lambda=n$ so this process recovers $n$ from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, that is $mm^*=nId$. Namely the matrix multiplication is a rescaled "Partial Isometry".

Comment: But the standard trace on $M_n$ has $tr(I) = n$. If you normalize it so $tr(I) = \lambda$ then you'll get $mm^* = \lambda Id$.

Comment: @NikWeaver, I think you actually get $mm^{\ast}= \frac{n^2}{\lambda} Id$. Anyway, one can assume that we that we have a tracial state, and then we get $n^2$, without any ambiguity depending on arbitrary choices. On the other hand, multiplication map is only bounded in the the finite-dimensional case, and then there exists a unique tracial state which gives $mm^{\ast}=\lambda Id$, and $\lambda$ is then the dimension of the algebra, so it has to be an integer. Maybe I will turn this into a short answer.

Comment: @MateuszWasilewski: yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nik Weaver mentioned, you can change the constant appearing in the equation $m m^{\ast}=\lambda Id$ by simply rescaling the inner product, so we need to assume some normalisation. I will work in the following framework. Let $A$ be a $C^{\ast}$-algebra and let $\varphi$ be a state on $A$. We call $\varphi$ a $\delta$-form if the multiplication map $A\otimes A \to A$ is bounded with respect to the inner product $\langle a, b\rangle = \varphi(a^{\ast}b)$ and $mm^{\ast}=\delta^2 Id$. What we are after are tracial $\delta$-forms.

Let's show that if $A$ is infinite dimensional then it does not admit a tracial state with respect to which the multiplication map is bounded. Indeed, let $(e_i)_{i\leq N}$ be an orthonormal set (because $A$ is infinite dimensional, $N$ can be arbitrarily large). Consider the element $x=\sum_{i=1}^{N} e_i^{\ast}\otimes e_i$. Then $m(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} e_{i}^{\ast}e_{i}$ and the $L^{2}$-norm of this element is at least $N$; indeed, the state $\varphi$ is contractive on $A$ equipped with its $L^{2}$-norm, and $\varphi(\sum_{i=1}^{N} e_i^{\ast}e_i) = N$. On the other hand, the $L^{2}$-norm of $\sum_{i=1}^{N} e_{i}^{\ast}\otimes e_i$ is equal to $\sqrt{N}$ (because $\varphi$ is tracial). Therefore the norm of $m$ is at least $\sqrt{N}$, but $N$ was arbitrary, so $m$ is not bounded.

So $A$ is finite dimensional, hence of the form $\oplus_{i=1}^{s} M_{n_i}(\mathbb{C})$. Every tracial state is specified by a sequence of weights $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_s)$, which add up to $1$. You can now check that it yields a $\delta$-form iff $\lambda_k = \frac{n_k^2}{\dim A}$. In this case $\delta^2 = \dim A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. BTW, in the case of matrix algebra, since the multiplication is a rescaled partial isometry, it would be interesting to have a precise representation for the verical space in $M_{n^2} (\mathbb{C})\simeq M_n(\mathbb{C})\otimes M_n(\mathbb{C})$. By vertical space I mean the orthogonal complement of the $\ker m$. It is (rescaled) isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. After this precise formulation of this vertical space, one can check whether it has generalization to $M_k$ where k is not a perfect square.

Comment: For n=2, what is an example of a 4\times 4$ vertical matrix? $I_4$ is not!

Comment: What about if we consider the unbounded but closable consideration?